# Django admin displays datetime fields inconsistently in Django admin view and in rendered tables

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I have a model that is an activity object to save api JSON data for database queries. The api sends a start date (UTC) and a local start date. I am experiencing an inconsistent treatment of the UTC time value and the local time value.

Model

```
class ActivityObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    moving_time = models.DurationField()
    elapsed_time = models.DurationField()
    total_elevation_gain = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    start_date_local = models.DateTimeField()
    average_speed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    max_speed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    average_cadence = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    has_heartrate = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    average_heartrate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    max_heartrate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    activity_logged_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'id %s----name %s----start date %s----start date local %s----logged date %s' % (self.id, self.name,
                                                                                               self.start_date,
                                                                                               self.start_date_local,
                                                                                               self.activity_logged_time)
```

[image: Admin list view]

[image: Admin item view]

The unexpected behavior is that the field values inside the object are reversed.

I get the values from API and convert the JSON to datetime objects.

```
start_date = a_row['start_date']
start_date_pretty = convert_json_to_datetime(start_date)
print('start date ', start_date_pretty)

start_date_local = a_row['start_date_local']
start_date_local_pretty = convert_json_to_datetime(start_date_local)
print('start date local ', start_date_local_pretty)
```

Relevant JSON key and values:

```
"start_date": "2022-11-04T21:01:20Z", "start_date_local": "2022-11-05T08:01:20Z",
```

I have

```
USE_TZ = True
```